# What is the best way to handle code with if/switch statements having high cyclomatic complexity?

Tags: java, sonarqube, static-analysis

I have a method that takes an input called capability id. Based on the capability id, I execute the business implementations put forward in form of a switch case. I have my functionality working, But came across a problem where the sonar report is showing high cyclomatic complexity around 12-14. The company I work for, uses a standard of 10 as the max cyclomatic complexity. My considerations is that, If I happen to break the code into too many block, the code readability is getting affected.

**Note:-**
I don't have permissions to change sonar rules.

Unfortunately, I can't share the code. The code would be in the following way though,

```
// Dependency Injected
private someService;

public void processCapability(..., String capabilityId) {
    switch (capabilityId) {
        case ORDER_DISPENSED_WITH_SOURCE1:
            someService.doDispense1();
        case ORDER_DISPENSED_WITH_SOURCE2:
            someService.doDispense2();
        case ORDER_REJECTED:
            someService.doReject();
        case ORDER_CANCEL:
            someService.doCancel();
        case ORDER_PURGE:
            someService.doPurge();
            ...
            default: throw exception
    }
}
```

**Update:** I was able to resolve my problem, with a solution I posted in below answers.

Comment: If there are 12-14 cases, there are 12-14 cases. Nothing you can do about that unless you are duplicating cases. Only solution is probably to restructure your overall approach, but I can't give you any advice on that because you haven't provided any code. Your company's rule is pretty bizarre though.

Comment: @Zarwan companies' rules always are. turns out management doesn't understand code.

Comment: "If I happen to break the code into too many block, the code readability is getting affected." -- generally the code readability is negatively affected if you do *not split* into smaller blocks (aka methods). However they need to have a good name that describes what the method does and have clear, single function.

Comment: I have faced similar issue in recent times. As you haven't shared any code snippet, please let me know how many lines are present under each case. What I mean is, if you have multiple lines of code that needs to be executed for each case then you can extract those lines into small functions and if possible try to write some common code for all the cases. That's all I can say without the actual code.

Comment: Would polymorphism be suitable to reduce the cyclomatic complexity ?

Comment: Try to include the various methods in an enum. I've provided a possible usage in my answer.

Comment: I'm also using dependency injection, Would combination of enum/dependency injected object create more complexity?

Comment: Well, I use dependency injection with enums quite often, and also a lot of strategy patterns. It depends on your situation which is more appropriate. If it seems that you can't have enums, try to use the strategy pattern, as I've recommended in my answer's 1. point. (the link helps)

Comment: @abbath Planning to give strategy design pattern a try today.

Comment: @Spotted Tried polymorphism created two methods process(..., String capapability) and another process(String capability,...). Solution works and called one method from another, but it didn't look good for what I have written.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I have couple of those code, where I can split into multiple methods too. I'm just having little bit difficulty breaking so that even others can understand.

Comment: @Zarwan, nhouser9, Suyash, I can't put the code here. But I did include a sample of how it is, in the description above.

Comment: do you have Java 8? I'd go with a Map<String, Consumer<Service>> or something like that, you could use an EnumMap

Comment: another solution is to mark the issue as won't fix with a comment explaining why you won't fix the issue

Comment: @Teryk-SonarSourceTeam Yes. We are using Java 8. I got a way of fixing this, That I have updated in the answers below.

Comment: @Teryk-SonarSourceTeam I didn't get to work with EnumMap before. I will look into that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured one way to handle the big if/switch statements. Based on the ideas, I got from everyone of you. I compiled into a simple solution that is easy to understand and modify, also handles the complexity part. Please find my solution below,

```
// Dependency Injected
private someService;

public void processCapability(..., String capabilityId) {

  Boolean isCapabilityProcessed = processDispenseCapabilities(...) || processUpdateCapabilities(..);

  if(isCapabilityProcessed) {
    throw exception("Invalid Capability");
  }
}

private Boolean processDispenseCapabilities(..,String capabilityId) {

  Boolean result = false;

  switch (capabilityId) {
        case ORDER_DISPENSED_WITH_SOURCE1:
            someService.doDispense1();
            result = true;
        case ORDER_DISPENSED_WITH_SOURCE2:
            someService.doDispense2();
            result = true;
        case ORDER_REJECTED:
            someService.doReject();
            result = true;
            ...
        default: //do nothing
    }

  return result;
}

private Boolean processUpdateCapabilities(..,String capabilityId) {
  Boolean result = false;

    switch (capabilityId) {
        case ORDER_CANCEL:
            someService.doCancel();
            result = true;
        case ORDER_PURGE:
            someService.doPurge();
            result = true;
            ...
        default: //do nothing
    }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to avoid large `if-else` statements.

Maybe the most common patterns are the `template method pattern` and the `strategy pattern`.

As you haven't provided any code, it's hard to help you to lower the cyclomatic complexity, but I'm absolutely sure, there's a way to avoid those `if-else`-s.

I'd suggest you to read a bit about the topic; I'll provide you some sources I've found useful:

1. [Using strategy to replace if else](https://industriallogic.com/xp/refactoring/conditionalWithStrategy.html)
2. [Using command pattern to replace conditional logic](https://industriallogic.com/xp/refactoring/conditionDispatcherWithCommand.html)
3. I'd encourage you to use enums, they are more usable in conditional logic than you'd think: [using enums instead of switch](https://schneide.wordpress.com/2010/12/13/avoid-switch-use-enum/)
4. Also it's good to know about various design patterns, maybe you can find a suitable one [here](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns)

Also a readable code means it's easy to understand. I agree with @Erwin Bolwidt's comment, if you create more methods with good names, it will be easier to read. To read more about the topic, check the book "Clean Code" by Robert C. Martin.

Comment: I considered implementing Strategy. But I felt like that would be overkill and make the code a tad more difficult to read for the other developers.

Comment: Well, I think it's harder for beginners, but in the end, when you'll need to add one or more cases to the existing if-s, it will be an unmaintainable mess.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you refactor this switch statement (which is a code smell) using polymorphism. A possible way to do it is something like that:

```
public interface Order {
    void processCapability(...);
}

public final class RejectedOrder implements Order {
    private final SomeService someService;

    public RejectedOrder(SomeService someService) {
        this.someService = someService;
    }

    @Override
    public void processCapability(...) {
        someService.doReject();
    }
}

public final class CancelledOrder implements Order {
    private final SomeService someService;

    public RejectedOrder(SomeService someService) {
        this.someService = someService;
    }

    @Override
    public void processCapability(...) {
        someService.doCancel();
    }
}
```

More useful resources talking about the 'switch smell':

- http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html
- http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SwitchStatementsSmell

Comment: One question. How do I know that the capability goes into Rejection/Cancellation/Dispense classes that implement Order?

Comment: @daemon54 Every case of the switch can be extracted into a separate class implementing `Order`.

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing wrong with your code, why make it more complex only to avoid SonarQube warnings? You might not be allowed to change SonarQube rules, but you certainly can suppress the warning by annotating your method with the following:

```
@SuppressWarnings("squid:MethodCyclomaticComplexity")
```

Comment: I don't want to suppress, So that's not an option I can use.